# Successfully connect Client to MySQL server

Tags: mysql, networking, database-connection

I see a lot of queries about how to connect a client to a MySQL server when the connection is refused or unsuccessful. In the interest of simplifying responses in the future, I am going to post a simple diagram of connection needs at the IP and MySQL Level. I will add description to each section when need be.

Answer (score 2):

To connect from a client machine to a MySQL DB, the data has to traverse up to 5 levels of validation. Here's a general case where the client and server are not on the same network and a secure connection is not used:

First make sure MySQL is using a `bind-address` that is different from `localhost` so it uses an interface and not just local connections.

[image: MySQL Connection Needs]

At each level, the firewall rules/permissions have to allow the connection to go through. Note that a machine can and often has a different IP internally than externally. The basic principle is:

> The Client **external** IP has to be allowed to connect to the DB **internal** IP, through all the levels.

Most of the time, the firewalls are properly configured. The last piece often missing the MySQL server `GRANT`ing permission to the `DB` for the external user. The last syntax is:

[MySQL Grant Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html)

Which often has the form:

```
GRANT ALL ON <DB>.* TO '<external_user>'@'<external_ip>' IDENTIFIED BY 'external_password';
```

Comment: Are you the author of the diagram ? If so, I would suggest dropping the green lines for each step, putting more space between the steps so nobody mixes the green boxes with any other step, and adding lines between the steps in the left column (would help representing the actual network links). This is picky however, your diagram is cool!