# Why is my port 3306 closed even though I do not have bind-address and skip-networking line at all?

Tags: mysql, macos, firewall

I have a web service with mysql running on a Mac OS X VMware Fusion image inside of a Mac OS X host. Both Macs are showing Firewall:Off under Security & Privacy.

When I do `telnet localhost 3306` or `telnet 127.0.0.1 3306`, I am able to connect. However if I do `telnet SERVERDOMAIN 3306`, it is not reachable.

On the Mac there are no bind-address or skip-networking line in .cnf file at all. In `mysql -help -verbose`, bind-address is showing as * and skip-networking is FALSE;

In mysql.user I only see localhost under host column and I have already used GRANT to grant access to both root and another user. (Since telnet to 3306 is failing, I don't think we are there yet.)

What else are we missing that could cause me not able to connect to the mysql remotely?

Comment: *telnet SERVERDOMAIN 3306, it is not reachable*  You are correct, this rules out *everything* related to permissions as being a problem.  It also rules out `bind` and skip-networking, both of which would result in `Connection refused`.

Answer (score 1):

For a general view of connecting to MySQL:

[Connect to MySQL from external machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46531115/successfully-connect-client-to-mysql-server/46531116#46531116)

In your case, you are on the same subnet, so you can forget the routers/internet part.

Comment: Most answers here related to remote access says using # to comment out bind-address. Doesn't that mean no bind-address?

Comment: @zaolian You were right: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address

Comment: @zaolian, *most* of the time, you need a `GRANT` to external_ip.

Comment: I ran GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;

Comment: Time for stupid questions: From Client - can you ping server (not port 3306)?  Please share IPs if you don't mind