# MySQL connection fails with one database and not with other

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 2 databases on mysql. **ge** and **ge_sc001**.

I can access both of these through my asp.net mvc application locally.

**Web.config**

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="GEContext_sc001" connectionString="server=localhost;port=3306;uid=root;pwd=***;database=ge_sc001" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
<add name="GEContext_sc002" connectionString="server=localhost;port=3306;uid=root;pwd=***;database=ge" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
<add name="GEContext" connectionString="server=localhost;port=3306;uid=root;pwd=***;database=ge" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

Later on when i deployed my application on the web server, and tried to access them from my local machine. I changed **server=localhost** to my machine's external-facing IP address. Now I can access only one **ge**. when i try to access the second it gives me error.

> Access denied for user 'root'@'' to database 'ge_sc001'

Notice there is no localhost above i.e. 'root'@'localhost'

**SHOW GRANTS**

'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO \'root\'@\'localhost\' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD \'*xxx\' WITH GRANT OPTION'
'GRANT PROXY ON \'\'@\'\' TO \'root\'@\'localhost\' WITH GRANT OPTION'

### Some Extra Info

Since asp.net mvc checks for a database connection before launching the application I have a default database on the server which is defined as GEContext. As you can see the database name there is also ge. I have not changed this connection string at all so it still points to localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `GRANT` **from** your external IP for **`ge_sc001`**

[Connect from external IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46531115/successfully-connect-client-to-mysql-server/46531116#46531116)

The specific syntax (to run on the remote server) should be

```
GRANT ALL ON ge_sc001.* TO 'root'@'<external_ip>';
```

Where `<external_ip>` is your remote **client** EXTERNAL IP

A more general (I don't like it, too broad) would be:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '<password>' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

--- SIDE NOTE ---

There was a straggling entry in `mysql.user` table that was interfering. Removing that manually and using `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` cleared things up

Comment: After running this command i am getting error "The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string." now on both of the schemas

Comment: Please see the GENERAL FORM.
You can `REVOKE` a previous `GRANT`: 
`REVOKE ALL ON ge_sc001.* FROM 'root'@'<external_ip>;`

Comment: @Samra, what is the result of `SHOW GRANTS`

Comment: 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO \'root\'@\'localhost\' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD \'*xxx\' WITH GRANT OPTION'
'GRANT PROXY ON \'\'@\'\' TO \'root\'@\'localhost\' WITH GRANT OPTION'

Comment: these are 2 rows

Comment: Stupid question .. are you running these queries on the local machine or the remote server? Because the command I suggested is NOT listed here

Comment: i removed it REVOKE ALL ON ge_sc001.* FROM 'root'@'<external_ip>;

Comment: but now both of my schemas are not connecting remotely error "The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string"

Comment: ON THE NEW EXTERNAL SERVER, you don't have permission from the existing CLIENT machine. You **only** have permission on `localhost`
I think we are confusing your client machine external IP and server machine external IP

Comment: my web server is X and my database is on machine Y. i ran grant queries on machine Y. What are you saying?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155868/discussion-between-samra-and-jacques-amar).